# Renaming multiple files in directory using a specific string in each file

Tags: regex, powershell, rename

I have a folder with multiple files and need to rename them to a string inside of the folder.  The string is the date of interaction.

Currently the files are named as

```
AUDIT-1.log
AUDIT-2.log
AUDIT-3.log
```

ect..

I need to have them as

```
AUDIT-11-08-22-1.log
AUDIT-11-07-22-2.log
AUDIT-11-08-22-3.log
```

The issue I am having with the current iteration of the code, the dates of all files are collected and it attempts to rename the file with all dates

**EXAMPLE:**

```
NewName: 11-08-22 11-07-22 11-06-22 11-09-22 11-08-22 11-07-22 11-06-22 11-09-22-1.LOG
OldName: C:\TestTemp\AUDIT-2.LOG
```

There is only one date in each file.

**The following is my current code:**

```
$dir ="C:\TestTemp"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$dir\*.log"
$RegexDate = '\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d'

Measure-Command{

$file_map = @()
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $DateName= Get-Content $files | 
Select-String $RegexDate |
foreach-object { $_.Matches.Value } |
Select-Object
    $NewDateName= $DateName.replace('/','-')
$b = 1 
    $file_map += @{
        OldName = $file.Fullname
        NewName = "$NewDateName-$b.LOG" -f $(Get-Content $file.Fullname | Select-Object $NewDateName.Fullname)
    }
}

$file_map | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_.OldName -NewName $_.NewName }

}
```

Comment: `Get-Content $files` ? it should be `$file`. Also `Select-String` can read files ;) no need to `Get-Content`

Comment: hah, thank you.  I have been staring at this for far longer than I care to admit.  Much appreciated!

Comment: How about: `Select-String -Path "$dir\*.log" -Pattern '(\d+\/){2}\d+' | Rename-Item -NewName { $1,$2 = $_.FileName -split '-'; "$1-" + $_.Matches.Value.Replace('/','-') + "-$2" } -WhatIf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon), the immediate fix is to swap `$files`, for `$file`. For code brevity, here's a single pipeline solution you can implement to attain the same results:

```bash
Select-String -Path "$dir\*.log" -Pattern '(\d+\/){2}\d+' | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { 
        $_.FileName -replace '-', "-$($_.Matches.Value.Replace('/','-'))-" 
    } -WhatIf
```

Again, as mentioned in the comments, the use of `Select-String` allows the reading of file(s) presenting the opportunity to pipe directly into `Rename-Item` via *parameter binding* through its `Path` property. So, using a scriptblock for the new name replacement we're essentially *inserting* the value found from it's pattern matched into the file name where `-` would have been.

---

*The `-WhatIf` safety/common parameter can be removed when you've dictated those are the results you are after.*

Answer (score 2):

This will rename the files using their last write time.
If the files were already in that format, they will not be renamed.
There is a hashtable to track the increment of the suffix for the date of the file. This way the files can be organized by date.

```
$dir = "C:\TestTemp"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$dir\*.log"


#Hashtable to track the suffix for the files
[hashtable]$dateTracking = @{}

#Using padding to format the suffix with two digits, in case there more then 9 files
#incrase it if you have more then 99 files per day increase padding
$suffixPadding = '{0:d2}'

foreach ($file in $files) {
    #Don't rename files that were already renamed
    if ($file.Name -notmatch "AUDIT-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.log") {
        $date = $file.LastWriteTime.ToString("MM-yy-dd")
        #If the date is not entered in the hashtable add it with suffix 01
        if (-not $dateTracking.ContainsKey($date)) {        
            $dateTracking.Add($date, $suffixPadding -f 1)
        }
        #Else increment suffix
        else {
            $dateTracking[$date] = $suffixPadding -f ([int]$dateTracking[$date] + 1)
        }
        #Here we use the date in the name of the file and getting the suffix from the hashtable
        Write-Host "Renaming $($file.Name) to AUDIT-$date-$($dateTracking[$date]).log"
        Rename-Item -Path $file -NewName "AUDIT-$date-$($dateTracking[$date]).log"
    }
}
```